# Calculating Pearson's generalised statistic

Tags: r, poisson-regression

I have a poisson regression model (`pbest = (V3~V2+L4+V5+V2*L4*V5,family=poisson)`) which has a summary of

```
Call:
glm(formula = V3 ~ V2 + L4 + V5 + V2 * L4 * V5, family = poisson, 
    data = doctor)

Deviance Residuals: 
       1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9  
-0.18821   0.27417  -0.17428   0.07463  -0.01969  -0.23669   0.27604  -0.13648   0.01482  
      10  
 0.01306  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   4.97196   29.09843   0.171    0.864
V2           -1.29138    3.38826  -0.381    0.703
L4           -0.01606    2.68444  -0.006    0.995
V5          -10.40090   23.13696  -0.450    0.653
V2:L4         0.07252    0.26893   0.270    0.787
V2:V5         0.12538    2.20347   0.057    0.955
L4:V5         0.71420    2.17130   0.329    0.742
V2:L4:V5      0.15821    0.17321   0.913    0.361

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 644.26899  on 9  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:   0.29816  on 2  degrees of freedom
AIC: 71.366

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3
```

I want to calculate the generalised Pearson statistic = $$1/(n-p) * sigma[(obs-fitted)^2/Var(μ)]$$. I know that n=10,p=8 and obs-fitted=V3-fitted.values(pbest), but have no clue of finding the variance of the model. How would you do this?

Comment: Please edit the post to include the equation as LaTeX. If 
it helps, we have some 
[resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/155836).

Comment: It is difficult to see how this statistic (however one might interpret the undefined symbol "$\mu$") would be relevant for a Poisson regression.  Could you explain how you would interpret it?